# Google Script HMAC SHA512 output differs when adding '\n'

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, sha, hmac, sha512

I'm trying to create a google script that generates a HMAC signature using SHA512 for authentication to an API. Here is the code I'm using:

```
     var SystemTimeMilli = Date.now()

     var InputString = ('Some Text' + '\n' + SystemTimeMilli);

     var PrivateKey = 'bEDtDJnW0y/Ll4YZitxb+D5sTNnEpQKH67EJRCmQCqN9cvGiB8+IHzB7HjsOs3mSlxLmu4aiPDRpe9anuWzylw=='  //sample private key

     var signature = Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, InputString, PrivateKey, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8));

     Logger.log(signature);
```

This generates a string to the log but when compared to results using web based hash generators the results differ.

However if I use

```
var InputString = ('Some Text' + SystemTimeMilli);
```

without the `\n` the results generated in my Google Script and the web based hash generators match.

So I'm assuming the way Google Script is handling the new line is different to the web base generators but I can't figure out how to get them match or which one is the correct result.

EDIT

To add some further information:
Lets say `SystemTimeMilli = 1234567890123`

When I enter `('Some Text' + SystemTimeMilli)` into my script using
`bEDtDJnW0y/Ll4YZitxb+D5sTNnEpQKH67EJRCmQCqN9cvGiB8+IHzB7HjsOs3mSlxLmu4aiPDRpe9anuWzylw==` as the `PrivateKey`

I get
`oDVJk38b634G9Ykdqm+hVmSb5C8h6/re5/XG+MjyddTKygWcoZjWu0DfNGY/JWu5Be41zLDKfEZnuFcACrvs7w==` returned.

Which is the same if I enter `/account/balance1234567890123` into https://quickhash.com using SHA-512 (SHA2) as the Algorithm and Base64 Encoding as the Output Format.

However if I enter `('Some Text' + '\n' + SystemTimeMilli)` in my script it returns `3sj1jbx1tQ4nc8XOkk3nW8TvG5zvCam2LN51fQWDXOKU5O/1KBAdzdp+YV+aAdYHWCY2x3jqCfbXKoOmfoD0KA==`

But using

`/account/balance
1234567890123`

in quickhash.com returns something different. I've tried a whole bunch of different combinations but I never get the same result as my script.

I having trouble with getting my script to authenticate to the API so I really want to determine if I'm getting the correct HMAC to begin with.

Comment: every character in the input string will change the hash - so, perhaps the "web based hash generators" **don't** have a `\n` where you've arbitrarily put one

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda X, I understand that every character will change the hash. I've added some addition info to the original post that might provide some more insight to my problem.

Comment: quickhash.com contains the probable answer to your question in it's warning: `(warning: be careful with newlines, browsers usually convert '\n' to '\r\n' when pasting -- work around coming soon)` If you change your script to use `\r\n` instead of just `\n` it should match quickhash.com's output.

Comment: Thanks Corey, you're right! I did see that warning but figured if I copy/pasted my code into the `Input Data` box then the `\r\n` issue would occur but if I typed it in manually I would get around it. 

Looks like I assumed to much. Ok... well at least I know my hash script is working. Thanks for your help.